# Under which condition this limitation is zero

Tags: limits, analysis

Under which condition on $\sigma$
such that the following limitation equals to zero?

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n \exp\left(\frac{-n^2/\sigma^2}{10n-4}\right)=0$$

Note: $\sigma$ is allowed to depend on $n$.

Comment: Is $\sigma$ allowed to depend on $n$? If it is a constant then this limit is zero (as long as $\sigma\neq 0$).

Comment: could the downvoted be explained? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\sigma=o(n^{3/4})$ then the limit is zero. Otherwise, if $\sigma=\Omega(n^{3/4})$, the limit is infinite.

---

#### Reasoning

Let $\sigma = n^a$. Then notice that
$$-\frac{(n^2/\sigma^2)^2}{10n-4}=-\frac{n^{4-4a}}{10n-4},$$
which is better than constant for any $a<\tfrac34$.

Now $n e^{-f(n)}\to 0$ for any $f(n)=\omega(\log n)$, so that's what I'm using here.

If you want to get more familiar with these asymptotic bounds, I highly suggest reading chapter 9 of Knuth's Concrete Mathematics.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you give the process to deducting this bound? I am not familiar with it, and which book I should look into?

Comment: I'll edit my answer.

Comment: And how does this compared to the condition $\sigma<\sqrt{\frac{n}{(2+\epsilon)log n}}$ (there exists $\epsilon>0$)? Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Hb_dynamics Where is that condition coming from? It's essentially $n^{1/2-\epsilon}$, which is $o(n^{3/4})$, but you can take a "larger" function such as $\sqrt[4]{n} \sqrt{\frac{n}{\log n}}$ (or just $\sqrt n$) in place of $\sigma$ and the limit would still be zero.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on ‘ which is better than constant for any $a<3/4$’? I understand that now we need $-\frac{n^2/\sigma^2}{10n-4}=\omega(\log n)$, but I don’t know how to obtain $a<3/4$. And thank you for the book, this is exactly what I need.

Comment: If you plug in $n^a$, then the numerator has power $4-4a$, and in order for this to beat the denominator, it needs to be greater than $1$.

Comment: It seems that the question has been changed.

Comment: yes, then the condition should be $\sigma=o(n^\frac{1}{2})$. Note that the case of $\sigma∼n^\frac{1}{2}$ is not considered yet..